# Is it possible to attach multiple ingress resources to an Application Pod in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nginx-ingress

I have a NGINX Ingress controller and multiple ingress resources attached to each pod in GKE. I want to know if I can attach more than one ingress resource to a single pod.

For example I have a Java application running on a pod and I have attached an ingress resource to it. The application can be accessed at `example.dev.com` and it already has a ssl cert attached to it which I don't want to touch. I want the same application to be accessed via `example.com` by attaching a new Ingress resource and applying a new SSL certificate and hostname `example.com` .
Is it possible ?
Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

> For example I have a Java application running on a pod and I have
> attached an ingress resource to it. The application can be accessed at
> example.dev.com and it already has a ssl cert attached to it which I
> don't want to touch. I want the same application to be accessed via
> example.com by attaching a new Ingress resource and applying a new SSL
> certificate and hostname example.com . Is it possible ? Any leads will
> be appreciated.

Create another ingress with an **SSL** cert stored into the secret and attach that secret to the new ingress.

make sure you are providing different names in the new ingress so it won't overwrite the existing one.

You can keep both config inside single file or else make different ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-wildcard-host
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
      - example.dev.com
    secretName: testsecret-tls
  rules:
  - host: "example.dev.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/bar"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: "example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/foo"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
```

If you have a single wild card **SSL**

```
tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.dev.com
      - example.com
    secretName: testsecret-tls
```

If you don't want both together just create once ingress for `example.com` as you want

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
    secretName: testsecret-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
```

Ref :https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/